# How do I set a max limit to a counter of a onclick event?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to add a max limit to the counter I have and I don't understand how to go about this.

- How do I set a max limit to a counter of a onclick event?
- Do I need an `if` statement? If so how would I write it?
- Do I need to change anything on the html part of it? If so what?
- If you can show me an example using my demo names of the function/variable  ex.(`goldClick`, `gold`) it would help me tremendously.
- If a secondary function/variable needs a name add `silver` and `copper` to the name so I know its different.,

```js
var gold = 0;
function goldClick(){
   gold = gold + 1;
   document.getElementById("gold").innerHTML = gold;
};
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="goldClick()">Gold</button>
<p>Gold:<a id="gold">0</a>/50</p>
```

Comment: these were all very helpful answers thank you all. i was able to understand it all alot better thank to all theses example and came out with this outcome to work the best for my intention of a game resource/currency/money/etc limiter. feel free to use this. this allows you to affect the max resources threw various ways.

Comment: Accept the appriate answer and upvote them.

Answer (score 1):

You only just need to place an `if` statement like this

```js
var gold = 0;
var goldMaxLimit = 15;
function goldClick(){
   if(gold <= goldMaxLimit){
       gold = gold + 1;
       document.getElementById("gold").innerHTML = gold;
    }
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="goldClick()">Gold</button> <p>Gold:<a id="gold">0</a>/50</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

With a simple if statement you can achieve this. Define a variable `limitCounter` and check against it

```js
var gold = 0
var limitCounter = 5
function goldClick(){
   if(gold <limitCounter) {
     gold = gold + 1;
     document.getElementById("gold").innerHTML = gold;
   } else {
      alert("Limit reached");
   }
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="goldClick()">Gold</button>
<p>Gold:<a id="gold">0</a>/5</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

And ***if*** statment would do it:

```
function goldClick(){
   if(gold <= /*Enter max gold quantity*/){
       gold = gold + 1;
       document.getElementById("gold").innerHTML = gold;
   }
   // Here you can add an "else" statment!
};
```

Also, you could tell the user when the gold quantity reaches the maximum value, adding an ***else*** statment (where indicated above):

```
else {
    document.getElementById("gold").innerHTML = gold + " - you have reached the max gold amount!";
}
```

Hope this helped! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add an if statement and disable the button when your limit is reached:

```js
var gold = 0;
function goldClick(){
  gold = gold + 1;
  document.getElementById("gold").innerHTML = gold;
  if (gold >= 50) {
    document.getElementById("goldButton").disabled = "disabled";
  }
};
```

```html
<button id="goldButton" type="button" onclick="goldClick()">Gold</button>
<p>Gold:<a id="gold">0</a>/50</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

my formula for my answer to my question.

```js
var gold = 0;
var goldMaxLimit = 50;
function goldClick() {
  if (gold < goldMaxLimit) {
    gold = gold + 1;
    document.getElementById("gold").innerHTML = gold;
  };
};
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="goldClick()">Gold</button>
<div>Gold:<a id "gold">0</a>/50</div>
```